# View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE crashes WebView inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to create a `WebView` that collapses the toolbar on scroll and also hides an FAB. I have it all working but as soon as I set the `WebView` to `View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` the thing crashes. The crashes happen on 5.0 and higher. Below 4.4 it seems to work fine. The crash output is:

```
01-14 18:10:09.720 2941-3090/com.webviewtesthw D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-14 18:10:09.796 2941-3090/com.webviewtesthw I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-14 18:10:09.886 2941-3097/com.webviewtesthw E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-14 18:10:10.583 2941-2941/com.webviewtesthw W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2941
01-14 18:10:11.553 2941-2941/com.webviewtesthw W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2941
01-14 18:10:11.727 2941-3090/com.webviewtesthw W/OpenGLRenderer: Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (1088x4288, max=4096x4096)
01-14 18:10:11.728 2941-3090/com.webviewtesthw D/OpenGLRenderer: Current memory usage / total memory usage (bytes):
                                                                   TextureCache            57600 / 75497472
                                                                   LayerCache           17825792 / 50331648 (numLayers = 1)
                                                                     Layer size 1088x4096; isTextureLayer()=0; texid=7 fbo=0; refs=1
                                                                   Layers total   17825792 (numLayers = 1)
                                                                   RenderBufferCache           0 /  8388608
                                                                   GradientCache           40960 /  1048576
                                                                   PathCache                   0 / 33554432
                                                                   TessellationCache           0 /  1048576
                                                                   TextDropShadowCache         0 /  6291456
                                                                   PatchCache                  0 /   131072
                                                                   FontRenderer 0 A8     1048576 /  1048576
                                                                   FontRenderer 0 RGBA         0 /        0
                                                                   FontRenderer 0 total  1048576 /  1048576
                                                                 Other:
                                                                   FboCache                    0 /        0
                                                                 Total memory usage:
                                                                   18972928 bytes, 18.09 MB
01-14 18:10:11.729 2941-2941/com.webviewtesthw D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-14 18:10:11.733 2941-2941/com.webviewtesthw E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.webviewtesthw, PID: 2941
                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView
                                                                     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My code is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.webviewtesthw.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.webviewtesthw.ScrollingActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/webview"></WebView>
            </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



package com.webviewtesthw;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCachePath(getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setSaveFormData(true);
   //     view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        view.loadUrl("http://vimeo.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT: if I set the height and width of the `WebView` to a fixed size then it works but as soon as I change it to match parent or wrap content it breaks. Also this issue does not happen if I take out the `NestedScrollView`

Comment: Your view is too wide.  From the log:   OpenGLRenderer: Layer exceeds max. dimensions supported by the GPU (1088x4288, max=4096x4096)

Comment: Sure but why? if I hardcode the width and height it works but if I set to wrap content or match parent it fails. I need it to take up the whole free space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug with `NestedScrollView`. 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578150

Answer (score 0):

If there is scrolling function or "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" line on the outer layout. Remove the nestedscrollview from the layout. It will not be necessary.